# Is there a data race?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, x86

```
class Test {  
  struct hazard_pointer {
        std::atomic<void*> hp;
        std::atomic<std::thread::id> id;
    };

  hazard_pointer hazard_pointers[max_hazard_pointers];

  std::atomic<void*>& get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread(){
        std::thread::id id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        for( int i =0; i < max_hazard_pointers; i++){
            if( hazard_pointers[i].id.load() == id){
                hazard_pointers[i].id.store(id);
                return hazard_pointers[i].hp;
            }
        }
     std::atomic<nullptr> ptr;
     return ptr;
    }
};

 int main() {
 Test* t =new Test();
 std::thread t1([&t](){ while(1) t->get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();});
      std::thread t2([&t](){ while(1) t->get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread();});
 t1.join();
 t2.join();
 return 0;
 }
```

The function `get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread` can be executed parallelly. Is there `data race`? On my eye there is no `data race` because of atomic operation, but I am not sure.

So, please make me sure or explain why there is ( are ) data race(s).

Let's assume that `hazard_pointers` array elements are initialized.

Comment: Can you post a CWME? How is this being called? Are the hazard_pointer id's being set before this function is called? Is there a barrier between them being set and this function being called?

Comment: I added an example of usage. Your other questions doesn't matter in that context

Comment: It returns a reference to a local variable - undefined behaviour.

Comment: What is `std::atomic<nullptr>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have any C++ UB from concurrent access to non-atomic data, but it looks like you do have [the normal kind of race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example) in your code.

`if (x==a) x = b` almost always needs to be an atomic read-modify-write (instead of separate atomic loads and atomic stores) in lock-free algorithms, unless there's some reason why it's ok to still store `b` if `x` changed to something other than `a` between the check and the store.

(In this case, the only thing that can ever be stored is the value that was already there, as @MargaretBloom points out.  So there's no "bug", just a bunch of useless stores if this is the only code that touches the array.  I'm assuming that you didn't really intend to write a useless example, so I'm considering it a bug.)

---

Lock-free programming is not easy, even if you do it the low-performance way with the default `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for all the stores so the compiler has to `MFENCE` everywhere.  Making everything `atomic` only avoids C++ UB; you still have to carefully design the logic of your algorithm to make sure it's correct even if multiple stores/loads from other thread(s) become visible between every one of your own operations, and stuff like that.  (e.g. see [Preshing's lock-free hash table](http://preshing.com/20130605/the-worlds-simplest-lock-free-hash-table/).)

Being UB-free is necessary (at least in theory) but definitely not sufficient for code to be correct / safe.  Being race-free means no (problematic) races even between atomic accesses.  This is a stronger but still not sufficient part of being bug-free.

I say "in theory" because in practice a lot of code with UB happens to compile the way we expect, and will only bite you on other platforms, or with future compilers, or with different surrounding code that exposes the UB during optimization.

Testing can't easily detect all bugs, esp. if you only test on strongly-ordered x86 hardware, but a simple bug like this should be easily detectable with testing.

---

**The problem with your code, in more detail**:

You do a non-atomic compare-exchange, with an atomic load and a separate atomic store:

```
        if( hazard_pointers[i].id.load() == id){
            // a store from another thread can become visible here
            hazard_pointers[i].id.store(id);
            return hazard_pointers[i].hp;
        }
```

The `.store()` should be a `std::compare_exchange_strong`, so the value isn't modified if a store from another thread changed the value between your load and your store.  (Putting it inside an `if` on a relaxed or acquire load is still a good idea; I think a branch to avoid a `lock cmpxchg` is a good idea if you expect the value to not match most of the time.  That should let the cache lines stay [Shared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESIF_protocol) when no thread finds a match on those elements.)

Comment: "Lock-free programming is not easy". Indeed. But, is not it worth to broaden my horizons? 
Yes, I know that I can solved it with compare-exchange instruction. Does it mean that there is data race, but it is safe? Another situation:

`std::atomic<int> X; ` **Thread1:** `int k = X.load();` **Thread2**: X.store(2);` There is data race but it is safe- it is not UB, am I right?

Comment: @Gilgamesz: "broaden my horizons", yeah that's a good idea.  My point was that just making everything `std::atomic` is nowhere near sufficient for correct algorithms.  Yes, there's a data race, and it's safe only in the sense that there's no C++ UB.  **That's not what most people mean when they say a piece of lock-free code is "safe"**.  no-UB just means that and nothing more.  The possible behaviours are limited, but not limited to useful/correct behaviours.

Comment: @Gilgamesz: re: second example.  If `X` is a local with automatic storage, thread1 could read it uninitialized.  If it's a global, then the code is safe.  `k` gets either the original or the value thread2 stored.

Comment: " Yes, there's a data race, and it's safe only in the sense that there's no C++ UB. That's not what most people mean when they say a piece of lock-free code is "safe".  " So does exist special definition of `safety of lock-free code` or it just means that code `works as we expect`? ( what is pesky hard to be sure when it comes to lock-free programming).

Comment: @Gilgamesz:  The words "safe" and "correct" both imply bug-free and implementing the desired algorithm.  You wouldn't say the code in the question was "safe", because it breaks if both threads are running at once.  It just doesn't break in a "format your hard drive" way like C++ undefined behaviour theoretically allows.  "no-UB" is a necessary but not sufficient condition for code to be considered correct.  The usual term for describing it is UB-free, because it's just one class of bug that you're talking about not having.

Comment: "no-UB" is a necessary but not sufficient condition for code to be considered correct" Of course. So, everything is clear. Thanks @Peter Cordes!

Comment: @Gilgamesz: Another useful term: "Race-free" means no harmful data races, including non-UB races between std::atomic variables.

Comment: I'm not sure there really is a data race, unless I've misinterpreted the code. Considering that `hazard_pointers[i].id.store(id);` combined with the condition one line above is "idempotent", it doesn't matter if another thread stores to `id` since it will store the same value anyway. Basically, removed the useless stores, the array is only read.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Oh hmm, I guess you're right, because technically this whole program never runs any code that ever stores a value other than what was already there.  So a store from another core that becomes visible between our load and our store could only have stored the value we already saw.  That's hilarious.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in the code:

1. `get_hazard_pointer_for_current_thread` may not return any value - undefined behaviour.
2. `hazard_pointers` array elements are not initialized.
3. `if(hazard_pointers[i].id.load() == id) hazard_pointers[i].id.store(id);` does not make any sense.

---

And yes, there is a data race. Between statement `if(hazard_pointers[i].id.load() == id)` and `hazard_pointers[i].id.store(id);` another thread may change `hazard_pointers[i].id`. You probably need to use a compare-and-swap instruction.

Comment: heh, just finished typing my answer about the race condition a few seconds after your edit.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did notice that :)